# jQuery doesn't respond when visibility="false" removed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a button that appears after a method in c# is completed:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click1" visible="true"/>
         <button runat="server" class="submit2" id="closeWidget" visible="false">Close</button>
      </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="submit" EventName="Click"/>
  </Triggers>
```

```
$('.submit2').click(function () {
   $('.widly').removeClass('window');
})
```

The problem is that when my method makes '.submit2' visible, my jQuery script doesn't recognize when i click on it.. However if i make it visible=true before the method is run, it works perfectly well.

So my question is, how do i make this work, after i change the visibility to true?

Comment: Please show the jquery script. It is very likely you are not using live binding.

Comment: i will update my question

Comment: Try this: `$('body').on('click', '.submit2', function () { $('.widly').removeClass('window'); })`

Comment: It works! Can you post it in an answer so i can approve it? Anyway, are you able to explain why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using

```
visible="false"
```

the control is removed from the HTML output. If you just want to hide it, you can use the display style instead:

```
<button runat="server" class="submit2" id="closeWidget" style='display: none;'>Close</button>
```

Then you can show it by removing the display style attribute.